# Can Flutter for Web show Pdf or Webview?

Tags: pdf, web, flutter, webview

I try to show pdf documents on flutter web, I am very new to flutter and not sure whether the Webview and Pdf plugin is available on flutter web yet. if yes can you please show me some example links? If not, is there any alternative solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

You can use **WebView()** widget to show PDF online and it works fine. Here is the Code,

```
WebView(
        initialUrl: ('https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=${yourPdfPath}'),
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      )
```

Comment: I am getting a blank view, any idea why?

Comment: @nani is yourPdfPath local ?

Comment: @Redanium No it is not. Its online.

Comment: sometimes it shows a blank page, it's kinda frustating

Comment: This works only if pdf file size is small size otherwise this will not work. Not worked for me in case of 432 KB size pdf file. Thanks

Comment: @Kamlesh really? It should work for large pdf too. anyway for that case, alternative solution would be a package

Comment: @AlWalidAshik Yes dear, its true. I have just updated my app by removing this `WebView` widget for displaying pdf files and added 2 new packages to solve it - `flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.1` and `permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2` Now I can load any size of pdf file in the app. It worked like charm for me. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: yes its workings  but there is a problem scroll is not working

Comment: @Kamlesh will you please explain how you did

Answer (score 8):

The best way is to use Google Docs Viewer.

Convert your pdf URL from(for example:)

"https://yourdomain.com/yourpdffile.pdf"

to

"https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://yourdomain.com/yourpdffile.pdf"

And then use it in your WebView

Comment: Worked for me. Just used the `url_launcher` and using `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=` as prefix.

Comment: but my file contain local path like ""storage/emulate/0/" how can i display document files

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you can display PDF documents and visit online websites using the add-in:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
html.window.open('http:///www.website.com/document.pdf');
```

or generate pdf documents using the add-in: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf.

I hope I have resolved the doubt, regards.

Comment: How to you use the generated pdf file with html.window.open()?

Comment: It throws me "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'dart: html'.  Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist."

Comment: There should be no extra space when u are importing this package. Update answer to: import 'dart:html' as html;

Answer (score 1):

I tried many of these plugins for PDF rendering on web, and found out that this is the best package for that, the most reliable:

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer